# Some things about maximal tori

Tags: algebraic-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over an algebraic closed field of characteristic $p\neq 2$. Suppose $\overline{G}_{\sigma}={G}_{\sigma}/Z({G}_{\sigma})$ where ${G}_{\sigma}$ is the set of fixed points of automorphism $\sigma$ on $G$. So $\overline{G}_{\sigma}$ is a finite simple group over a finite field of characteristic $p\neq 2$.

Let $\{T_i:1\leq i\leq n\}$ be the set of maximal tori of $G$. It is well known that $T_i$'s are pairwise conjugat in $G$. Now Let $\{\overline{T}_i:1\leq i\leq m\}$ be the maximal tori of $\overline{G}_{\sigma}$. We know that $m\leq n$ and $\overline{T}_i$ is not necessarily conjugate to $\overline{T}_j$ for $i\neq j$ in $\overline{G}_{\sigma}$. But what else we can say?

1. If $\overline{T}_i$ is not conjugate to $\overline{T}_j$ then $\overline{T}_i\cap \overline{T}_j=\{1\}$?
2. If $|\overline{T}_i|=|\overline{T}_j|$ then are they conjugate?
3. $\cdots$

Comment: #1 no (also subgroups always contain the identity). #2 no, I think I gave examples already.

Comment: Question had a typo! I corrected it now.

Comment: Would example G help? #1 is false even in PSL3. #2 is false in PSp4.

Comment: Yes, examples are good. However if there exists a proof to show that the answer is negative in (almost) all cases, is so much better!